# Object object is shown in select tag in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Data inside options(JSON) is

const options =  {"option":"Male","value":"M"};
Raect code is

```
{props.options.map((option) => {
      return (
         <option key={option.value} value={option.option}>
            <Translate>{option.option}</Translate>
         </option>
      );
})}
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Comment: Object Object is shown inside select tag . How can i display male inside select tag

Comment: From your sample code, you're trying to map an object. You can't map an object. Instead, you can use Object.values(options). It'll iterate through values i.e(Male & M). Also can you recheck if you've pasted the right code to see if options is an array?

Comment: @Sibabrat swain it didn't worked , still showing Object object and i have updated my React version from 16.3 to 16.13 before updating it was working fine but after updating it shows object object

Comment: I can see your options are not in an array.

Comment: @vijay Krishna it is an Array

Comment: I think @sibabratswain solution will work for you. Next time please add the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You are interpreting the map in the wrong way. Please follow this and use it in a similar way. Make sure the options are in an array.

```
const values = [{option: 'male': value: 'm'}, {option: 'female': value: 'f'}, {option: 'others': value: 'o'}];

function App() {
 return (
  <div>
    {values.map(val => (
      <option key={val.value} value={val.option}>
         <Translate>{val.option}</Translate>
       </option>
    ))}
  </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `map` through an object just to use its keys.

Instead simply do:

```
const options = {option: 'male': value: 'm'} // this is your parsed JSON

function App() {
 return (
  <div>
    <option key={options.value} value={options.option}>
        <Translate>{options.option}</Translate>
     </option>
  </div>
 );
}
```